# How do I select an individual element inside an if { } in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to be able to hide a selector if it contains any data.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
   var x= $('#ul li');

   if (x.html().length > 0) {
        $(this).hide();
   }
```

The $(this) isn't working, but I have no idea how to select it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to iterate them using `.each()`, then check the inner HTML of *each* element (that's where `$(this)` makes sense in your case):

```
x.each(function() {
    if ($(this).html().length > 0)
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to read up more about the if selector. I assume it only works inside functions. Thanks.

Comment: `if` is not a selector, it's a JavaScript keyword that basically checks a condition. You need jQuery methods like `.each()` in order to iterate (go through) the elements that you select.